plasmo chrome extentions oauth twitter login fail
i follow this docs to get user access tokens in plasmo extentions:
https://developer.x.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens
and when i finished the step1，i try step2 like this code:
const xLogin = () => {
    const redirectUri = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL('callback');
    const authUrl = `${userAuthorizeUrl}?oauth_token=${oauthConfig.oauth_token}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUri)}`;
    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
      {
        url: authUrl,
        interactive: true,
      },
      (redirectUrl) => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.log('@error', chrome.runtime.lastError)
          return;
        }
        const params = new URL(redirectUrl).searchParams;
        console.log('@redirectUrl', redirectUrl);
      }
    );
  }

but when i finished the twitter authorize, my xLogin callback don't work so i can't revecive the successful token.
what should i do to resolve it?
here my package.json:
{
  "name": "plasmo-demo",
  "displayName": "Plasmo demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A basic Plasmo extension.",
  "author": "none",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "plasmo dev",
    "build": "plasmo build",
    "package": "plasmo package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@plasmohq/messaging": "^0.6.2",
    "axios": "^1.7.3",
    "oauth-1.0a": "^2.2.6",
    "plasmo": "0.88.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ianvs/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "4.1.1",
    "@types/chrome": "0.0.258",
    "@types/node": "20.11.5",
    "@types/react": "18.2.48",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.18",
    "prettier": "3.2.4",
    "typescript": "5.3.3"
  },
  "manifest": {
    "host_permissions": [
      "https://api.twitter.com/"
    ],
    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "identity"
    ]
  }
}

i think there is someting wrong with my redirectUrl but i dont't know how to do the next steps
